# React native 'PlatformColor' was not found in 'react-native-web/dist/index'

Tags: react-native, dialog

I am getting a bunch of these:

1. WARNING in ./node_modules/react-native-dialog/lib/Button.js:45:19
2. WARNING in ./node_modules/react-native-dialog/lib/Button.js:51:19
3. WARNING in ./node_modules/react-native-dialog/lib/CodeInput.js:68:58
4. WARNING in ./node_modules/react-native-dialog/lib/CodeInput.js:70:25

And many more.

Error:
export 'PlatformColor' (imported as 'PlatformColor') was not found in 'react-native-web/dist/index' (possible exports: AccessibilityInfo, ActivityIndicator, Alert, Animated, AppRegistry, AppState, Appearance, BackHandler, Button, CheckBox, Clipboard, DeviceEventEmitter, Dimensions, Easing, FlatList, I18nManager, Image, ImageBackground, InteractionManager, Keyboard, KeyboardAvoidingView, LayoutAnimation, Linking, LogBox, Modal, NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules, PanResponder, Picker, PixelRatio, Platform, Pressable, ProgressBar, RefreshControl, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, SectionList, Share, StatusBar, StyleSheet, Switch, Text, TextInput, Touchable, TouchableHighlight, TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableOpacity, TouchableWithoutFeedback, UIManager, Vibration, View, VirtualizedList, YellowBox, findNodeHandle, processColor, render, unmountComponentAtNode, unstable_createElement, useColorScheme, useLocaleContext, useWindowDimensions)

[image]

It only happens in web mode. On iOS all looks good. What should I look into?

Thanks,
Asif

Answer (score 0):

I see u use "react-native-dialog"

According to [their docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dialog) they don't support web. If I remember right PlatformColor is only for iOS and Android.